# How to get images to show up on TExtButton in ExtPascal?

Tags: image, button, extjs, lazarus

I've been trying for hours in Lazarus following from the sample code in the 
AdvancedTabs unit, to make am image appear on a button.

The sample code has this:

```
constructor TAdvancedTabs.Create; 
var 
  I : integer; 
begin 
  inherited; 
  with SelfSession do begin 
    SetCodePress; 
    SetStyle('.new-tab{background-image:url(' + ExtPath + '/examples/feed-viewer/images/new_tab.gif) !important}'); 
    SetStyle('.tabs{background:url(' + ExtPath + '/examples/desktop/images/tabs.gif)}'); 
  end; 
  with TExtButton.Create do begin 
    RenderTo := 'body'; 
    Text     := 'Add Tab using AJAX!'; 
    IconCls  := 'new-tab'; 
    Handler  := Ajax(AddTab); 
    OnClick  := HandleExtButtonClick; // Delphi style event handler 
  end; 
...
```

I have this:

```
 extPath := (CurrentFCGIThread as TExtThread).ExtPath; 
  (CurrentFCGIThread as TExtThread).SetStyle('.backbtn{background-image:url(' + ExtPath + '/basxv2/back.png) !important}'); 
  btnClose := TV2ExtButton.Create; 
  with btnClose.AddTo(Items) do 
    begin 
    Id := 'frmManualOrder_btnClose'; 
    X := MarginLeft; 
    Height := ButtonHeight; 
    Y := ScreenHeight-12*MarginLeft; 
    Width := ButtonWidth-10; 
    RenderTo := 'body'; 
    IconCls := 'backbtn'; 
...
```

I have tried a number of different things, converting the image to a 
gif, for example, and in most cases the button is either blank (if I 
don't set the Text property) or shows the text nudged to the right a 
few pixels as if making room for an invisible image. A few times the image appears with the top and bottom clipped.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

TIA 
Mark